# How to construct an isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

I know the group $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_6$ (since $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_6$ since $2$ and $3$ are coprimes).

But how would I construct such an ismorphism?

Comment: You can use the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Theorem_statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it explicit by projecting the elements of $Z/6$ to the respective elements in $Z/3$ and $Z/2$, i.e. $$Z/6 \rightarrow Z/3 \times Z/2, i \mapsto (i \text{ mod } 3, i \text{ mod }2).$$ As you say, 2 and 3 are coprime and thus the Chinese remainder theorem tells you that this is an isomorphism.

Comment: The isomorphism is supposed to be between $Z_3 \times Z_3 \times Z_2$ and $Z_3 \times Z_6$

Comment: I think it is pretty obvious that you take the identity on the first component. Or am I overseeing something?

Answer (score 0):

An isomorphism $f: \mathbb{Z_3 \times Z_2}  \to \mathbb{Z_6}$ can be determined by $f(1,1) \to 1$

So it would make sense that the map $\mathbb{Z_3 \times Z_3 \times Z_2} \to \mathbb{Z_3 \times Z_6}$ could be given by

$$(0,a,b) \mapsto (0,f(a,b))
\\(1,a,b) \mapsto (1,f(a,b))\\(2,a,b) \mapsto(2,f(a,b)) $$

Comment: and a  ∈ Z3 and b ∈ z2?

Comment: $a \in Z_3$ and $b \in Z_2$

Comment: Yes, this is clearly a bijection.  Now just check that it's a homomorphism.